# Using material UI Icon in textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the material UI Filter Icon to appear in the Textfield that I have created but can't seem to get it to appear. Any ideas why?

```html
<TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" input type="search" placeholder="Filter" startIcon={<FilterAltIcon />}>
<TextField />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass your icon to `InputProps` of your `TextField` as `startAdornment` or `endAdornment` depending on where you would like to have an icon

```
<TextField
        id="input-with-icon-textfield"
        label="TextField"
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              < FilterAltIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        variant="standard"
      />
```